# SSIS use of JSON.NET in GAC for Script Component

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2012, json.net

I have built a Scopus Library (dll) which I load into the GAC for use by an SSIS package's script component.
This Library is based on the .Net framework 4.5 and utilizes the Json.Net Lib which I have also loaded into the GAC.

When run the package through the SSISDB in SSIS Catalogue on my loacal & Dev machines it works fine, When I have run it on the test machine in the same manner it fails with the following error.

> DFT - S_SCOPUS_PUBL_META_EXTRACT: Error: System.TypeloadException:
>   Could not load the type System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionart
>   '2' from assembly mscorlib, version 4.0.0.0 Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c661934e089.

at

```
Microsoft.SQLServer.Dts.Pipeline.SciptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception(e)
```

at

```
Microsoft.SQLServer.Dts.Pipeline.SciptComponentHost.
```

ect ect.

Box Setups:
SQL Server 2012, Server 2012 for Dev and Test and SQL Server 2012 & Windows 7 for Local.

---

Things I have attempted to fix the issue

1. Checked the Scopus Library, Json.Net and SSIS Script Component all use the 4.5 version of the .Net Framework.
2. Double checked that the Scopus and Json.Net Libraries are in the GAC correctly
3. Made sure I had the latest version of the Json.Net Library
4. Checked the version of the mscorlib.dll on each machine 
   LOCAL, DEV Machines are File Version 4.0.30319.18052
   TEST Machine is                  File Version 4.0.30319.1008
5. Ran a scan for updates on the TEST machine to see if it required any additional patches to update the mscorlib.dll file (it told me it was up to date - keep in mind I am not a sys admin so they might be holding back).

Does anyone have any additional idea's about how to get around this error ?

Comment: From the throwing something at the wall and see what sticks department: have you looked into possible 32 bit -- 64 bit issues? I am not convinced this is the problem, but with the different libraries you're using it's something I would try and rule out.

Comment: If you can RDC into the Test server, fire up a PowerShell instance load the assembly and try to use it. See if there's something weird going on. How about SQL Server, what patch level are they both at?

Comment: SQL Server DEV

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0

Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 11.0.3128.0

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514

Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0 

Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0.7601.17514

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.18052

Operating System 6.1.7601

Comment: TEST Box: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 11.0.3128.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0.7601.17514
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.1008
Operating System 6.1.7601

Comment: OK, so all your components require .NET framework 4.5, but your machines only have .NET framework 4.0?  Try installing the 4.5 framework.

Comment: I've put through a request to have the .Net framework version updated so I guess I'll see how that goes.

Comment: Sorry Correction Above: Swap my comments about .Net Framework 4.5 for 4.0. That being said I thought about Brian Rodgers comment and double checked versions again. Everything was .Net 4.0 until I looked at the version of JSON.Net which was 4.5. I downloaded the JSON.Net project again and used the version 4.0 Library. Made all the changes from my SCOPUS library, through GAC installs and :( no love still the same error.

Works on Local & Dev Machine but not on TEST

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if SSIS 2012 still has this behavior; however, in SSIS 2005 and 2008 I've found that GACing custom DLLs referenced by script components **isn't enough**. I also had to copy the custom DLLs to the target machine's .NET Framework folder, so that the SSIS runtime could find them when the package was validated.